# Subtract time from datetime.time object

Tags: python, datetime

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
current_time = datetime.now().time()
new_time = current_time - timedelta(seconds=10)
>> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'
```

How can I substract time from a datetime.time object? This code seems working only with datetime.datetime objects.

Answer (score 3):

You can just subtract 10 seconds from your current `datetime` object before returning the time.

```
current_time = (datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=10)).time()
```

Comment: is this still working? TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.timezone'

Comment: I double-checked and it's still working @greendino

Comment: ahh yes. mb @styvane

Answer (score 2):

Timedelta only works against datetime.datetime and datetime.date objects. But you could always do

```
current_dt = datetime.datetime.now()
newdt = currentdt - datetime.delta(seconds=10)
new_time = newdt.time()
```

Answer (score 1):

Get time after datetime subtraction:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
current_time = datetime.now()
new_time = current_time - timedelta(seconds=10)
new_time = new_time.time()
print new_time
```

output: 10:56:43.408337