# Getting current time minus 10 minutes in epoch with milliseconds

Tags: python-3.x, epoch

I would like to have a python3 script which gets the current time - 10 minutes and it converts it to epoch time in milliseconds

The problem is that I have no idea how to start.

something witch in bash looks like this:

```
$(( $(date -d '-10 minutes' +%s%N)/1000000 )))
```

Comment: [(1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/how-to-get-current-time-in-python) [(2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42594164/subtract-time-from-datetime-time-object) [(3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999726/how-can-i-convert-a-datetime-object-to-milliseconds-since-epoch-unix-time-in-p)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`datetime.datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime) and [`datetime.timedelta`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) to achieve that:

```
import datetime

current_time = datetime.datetime.now()  # use datetime.datetime.utcnow() for UTC time
ten_minutes_ago = current_time - datetime.timedelta(minutes=10)

ten_minutes_ago_epoch_ts = int(ten_minutes_ago.timestamp() * 1000)  # in miliseconds
```